# stellar.toml in a http server

Tags: compliance

I am setting up a private network on a local machine. I have stellar-core, horizon and bridge server running.
While setting up compliance server, it needs access to domain’s stellar.toml. This file has to be hosted https://domain/.well-known/stellar.toml.

In local test environment I do not have access to https / 443 server. Is it possible via some configuration, stellar.toml can be hosted on a http port

e.g. 
http://my.localhost/~Harmit/one/.well-known/stellar.toml (For Node set 1)
http://my.localhost/~Harmit/two/.well-known/stellar.toml (For Node set 2)

Thanks for all the help and support

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, all wallets and other clients search for `stellar.toml` using the HTTPS scheme, so HTTP setup just won't work. You can try to issue a [self-signed SSL certificate](https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) for your test domain.

In case if you have dedicated API and own some domain (say, `mypersonaldomain.com`), there is an easier way to achieve your goals. Using  https://certbot.eff.org/ you can generate a valid SSL certificate issued by [Let'sEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) absolutely free of charge.